# Can Safari extension call AppleScript?

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I wonder if safari extension allows interaction with other apps installed on the Mac.

If not, I am also considering an alternative to run an Apple script to interact with the content of a certain Safari tab. Is it much easier this way?

Thanks!

Comment: No, that's certainly not possible.